# Password input field length = 0 on autofill (android chrome)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-chrome, autofill

I am running a placeholder over an input field on a login page. On android (4.3) it auto fills the user and password fields on page load. Using Javascript I am able to get the length of the autofilled user input but when I run the same function on the password input it returns 0.

Even when I debug using Chrome Remote Debugging it show that the password input field is "" with a length = 0. Yet android chrome shows the password in the field.

Is there anyway around this. I just need detect when the input field is not empty so I can hide the placeholder.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert($("#password").val().length);
        checkPlaceholder("#password");
    }, 1000);
});

function checkPlaceholder(x) {
    if($(x).val().length === 0){
        $(x).parent().find(".input_placeholder").removeClass("placeholder_hide");
    }
    else {
        $(x).parent().find(".input_placeholder").addClass("placeholder_hide");
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd get quicker results if you add your code to this post.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had similar problem. And I didn't find any information about this. But I noticed, that Android Chrome fill password field with real value after user's tap on document body. After that password field generate `'change'` event, and if you check it's value it will be filled. Unfortunately Chrome doesn't work the same way if we trigger `'click'/'touch'/'focus' etc.` events, only hardware tap.

So, I resolved my problem by adding event listener for `'change'` event on password field. For you solution can be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // leave this code for other browsers
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert($("#password").val().length);
        checkPlaceholder("#password");
    }, 1000);
    // android Chrome fix
    $('#password').change(checkPlaceholder.bind(null, '#password'));
});
```

But, as I wrote before, that code will execute **ONLY** after user tap on page.

Comment: Same problem here, but still no solution